# My Date Object is not compiling in my Subroutine

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to compare today's month(date) with a string in the format of month("mm.dd.yyyy")
In my case:

```
Sub External_Number()
Dim exBreak As String
Dim theDate As Date
Dim dateString As String    

dateString = "11.24.19"
set theDate = format(CDate(dateString, "mm/dd/yyyy"))
If Month(theDate) = Month(Date) Then
'...........Blah Blah Blah
Else
exNum = 1
End If
End Sub
```

I am getting a object required error on the "set theDate" line.

Comment: Why not use `dateString` as a date? You will either need to convert the string to date or date to string to compare which seems like unnecessary work when you could just use the logical variable types here (*assuming it's logical given lack of context*)

Comment: Also, you don't use `Set theDate = Format(....` since it's not an object. You assign the value the same way you would a string (as you have done for `dateString`)

Comment: Ive been getting a type mismatch. I am not sure if this matters but the dateString was actually being set to a sheet.name which would return a date in a string format. Anyhow, I went with the below answer by @MRah which works. Thanks for the timely response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue 1: Date is not an Object in VBA. Just remove Set before theDate,

Issue 2: the format for the dateString is not a standard date format. The following code is one way to resolve this issue.

```html
Sub External_Number()
  Dim exBreak As String
  Dim theDate As Date
  Dim dateString As String    
  Dim iMonth as Integer
  Dim iDay as Integer
  Dim iYear as Integer
  Dim splitDate() as String

  dateString = "11.24.19"
  splitDate = Split(dateString, ".")

  iMonth = CInt(splitDate(0))
  iDay = CInt(splitDate(1))

  ' Please note that year will return only 19 and not 2019
  iYear = CInt(splitDate(2))


  ' theDate = format(CDate(dateString, "mm/dd/yyyy"))
  If iMonth = Month(Date) Then
  '...........Blah Blah Blah
  Else
  exNum = 1
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `Set` for objects and your variable is actually a date - thus no object exists to set. In short, remove `Set` from this line

```
theDate = format(CDate(dateString, "mm/dd/yyyy"))
```